# Show that $\inf\limits_{|x|\geq 1} 1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1-\sin(1)\geq \frac{1}{7}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

I am interested in showing that
\begin{eqnarray}
\inf\limits_{|x|\geq 1} \left(1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)=1-\sin(1)\geq \frac{1}{7}.
\end{eqnarray}

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Hint. We have that for $|x|\geq 2$,
$$1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\geq 1-\frac{|\sin(x)|}{|x|}\geq 1-\frac{|\sin(x)|}{2}\geq 1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Now show that the function $f(x)=1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ (which is even) is increasing in $[1,2]$.

Comment: Another (actually just slightly weaker) way could be showing that it has no extremal points in the interior, and then confronting the values at the boundary gives the claim

Answer (score 0):

Proof of $1-\sin(1)\geq \frac{1}{7}$:

Using Taylor's expansion we get,

$$ 1-\sin(1) = \frac{1}{3!} - \frac{1}{5!} + \frac{1}{7!} - \frac{1}{9!} +-\cdots \geq \frac{1}{3!} - \frac{1}{5!} = \frac{19}{120} > \frac{1}{7}. $$

Proof of first equality:

Will prove the claim mentioned by Mr. Robert Z, that is $f(x)=1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is increasing in $[1,2]$.

$f'(x)>0 \iff \tan(x) > x, x \in [1,2],$ which is true by taylor series expansion for $\tan(x)$.